# Is it possible to make a python bot that sends Youtube live chat messages?

Tags: python, youtube

I'm trying to make a youtube bot for a friend who streams often. I already looked into `pytchat`, which worked pretty well in retrieving chat messages, but I don't think it has a way to send messages. I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: Most likely, yes. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is completely possible.

Taking a brief look at `pytchat`, indeed it looks like it has no way to send messages.

But there is an [official API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/insert) to post messages. Depending on your experience level, you may find it easy to use it.

There are several ressources (YouTube videos, medium articles, ...) that explain how to use the API to build a rudimentary bot.